# Updating MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Does anyone know how I can update in MongoDB.

I want to update the totalVisits with timesvisted

```
// Test data
var currentUser = "John"
var currentPage = "pageName"
var timesvisited = 59


Page.find({"_id" : currentUser}, [], {},function(err, pages) {
            pages = pages.map(function(ud) {
              return { userDetails: ud};
            });


//database structure example
{ "_id" : "John",
  "pageName" : { "totalVisits" : 58,
                 "timeOnPage" : 2432,
                 "lastVisitDate" : "10/11/2011",
                 "clickNoOnPage" : "5"
               },
  "anotherPageName" : { "totalVisits" : 18,
                 "timeOnPage" : 5362,
                 "lastVisitDate" : "01/10/2011",
                 "clickNoOnPage" : "15"
```

I am trying to update the totalVisits value and have tried something like

```
{$set : { pages[0].userDetails[currentPage].totalVisits : timesvisted}}
```

However I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token [" message

One of the problems I am having is with the [currentPage] section as currentPage can change so I can not hard code the pageName in.

Edit *********

I have modified this line

```
lastVisitedSiteDate = {$set : { "pageName.totalVisits" : timesvist}};
```

and this works fine. However, I need the pageName not to be hard coded in, its needs to be something like currentPage so different page names can be passed into it e.g. anotherPageName.

Comment: Read this: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

Comment: You better post correct structure of the document on which you want to perform update.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to Mongo's `find` function specifies which fields to pull back. It needs to be a document, as in `{}`, not an array.